# Работа с несколькими блоками, js

Tags: javascript

День добрый, в скрипте по клику нужно скрыть отображаемые блоки, и отобразить только один (блоки выводятся через while т.е. id блока заранее не известно), скрипт делаю по принципу - скрыть все блоки а затем отобразить только тот, айди которого было передано в функцию, в итоге скрипт не работает, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

```
function displayBlock(hallId)
{
 document.getElementsByClassName("hidden_b").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("hidden_block_"+hallId).style.display = "block";
}

<div id="hidden_block_'.$hall_row['hall_id'].'" class="hidden_b" style="display:none;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayBlock('.$hall_row['hall_id'].');">Клик</a>

<div id="hidden_block_'.$hall_row['hall_id'].'" class="hidden_b" style="display:none;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayBlock('.$hall_row['hall_id'].');">Клик</a>

<div id="hidden_block_'.$hall_row['hall_id'].'" class="hidden_b" style="display:none;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayBlock('.$hall_row['hall_id'].');">Клик</a>
```

Comment: В функции onclick вы передаете непонятно что, а не hallId. К тому же у блоков вместо id непонятно что написано.

Comment: это выдержка из php скрипта, там передается простое число из массива $hall_row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив элементов. У массива нет свойства `style`. Чтобы изменить стиль у всех элементов массива нужно перебирать их в цикле и менять у каждого в отдельности. Или, что гораздо проще, использовать jQuery, где делается всё то же самое, но прозрачно для программиста. В jQuery эта строка выглядела бы так:

```
$('.hidden_b').css('display', 'none')
```

Или ещё проще:

```
$('.hidden_b').hide()
```